# How to compute $\int_0^1\frac{t\ln t}{1+t^2}$ ?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

> How to compute the integral $$\int_0^1\frac{t\ln t}{1+t^2}\ ?$$

So Wolfram alpha says it is exactly $-\dfrac{\pi^2}{48}$ .

I tried many substitutions without success, and partial integration as well.

Any help is welcome.

Comment: Shouldn't the integral be negative?

Comment: Forgot the minus sign, my bad.

Comment: Wolfram shows $Li_2$-terms in the antiderivate, so there is no easy antiderivate, but the terms obviously can be calculated exactly in this case. The other approach could be the residue theorem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Integrating by parts
$$
-\int_0^1\frac{t\ln t}{1+t^2}\,dt=\frac12\int_0^1\bigl(\log(1+t^2)\bigr)'\log t\,dt=\frac12\int_0^1\frac{\log(1+t^2)}{t}\,dt.
$$
Expad the integrand in a power series to get
$$
\int_0^1\frac{\log(1+t^2)}{t}\,dt=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n}\int_0^1t^{2n-1}\,dt=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n^2}.
$$
This is a well known sum.

Comment: Your last sentence is one big assumption :). BTW you forgot a minus sign from the beginning.

Answer (score 8):

I would expand $(1+t^2)^{-1}$ around $t=0$ and find out what $$\int_0^1 t^k \log t dt$$ is for each $k$.

**ADD** The sequence of functions $\displaystyle f_n=-t\log t\sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^k t^{2k}$ is dominated by $-t\log t$ over $[0,1]$ and converges to $f=-t\log t(1+t^2)^{-1}$ so Lebesgue's DCT ensures $$\int_0^1 \frac{t\log t}{1+t^2}dt= \sum_{k\geqslant 1}(-1)^k\int_0^1 t^{2k+1}\log t dt$$

Comment: Wouldn't there be some issues of uniform convergence? Why can you pass the integral through the sum?

Comment: @nayrb Consider them as Lebesgue integrals.

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}%
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle #1 \right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace #1 \right\rbrace}%
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack #1 \right\rbrack}%
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil #1 \right\rceil\,}%
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}%
 \newcommand{\down}{\downarrow}%
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\equalby}[1]{{#1 \atop {= \atop \vphantom{\huge A}}}}%
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}%
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}%
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}%
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}%
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}%
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}%
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}%
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left( #1 \right)}%
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}%
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,#2\,}\,}%
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}%
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}%
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
\color{#66f}{\large\int_{0}^{1}{t\ln\pars{t} \over 1 + t^{2}}\,\dd t}&=
\Re\int_{0}^{1}{\ln\pars{t} \over \ic + t}\,\dd t
=-\Re\int_{0}^{1}{\ln\pars{-\ic\bracks{\ic t}} \over 1 - \pars{\ic t}}
\,\pars{\ic\,\dd t}
=-\,\Re\int_{0}^{\ic}{\ln\pars{-\ic t} \over 1 - t}\,\dd t
\\[3mm]&=-\,\Re\int_{0}^{\ic}\ln\pars{1 - t}\,{1 \over -\ic t}\,\pars{-\ic}\,\dd t
=\Re\int_{0}^{\ic}{{\rm Li}_{1}\pars{t} \over t}\,\dd t
\end{align}
where $\ds{{\rm Li_{s}}\pars{z}}$ is a [PolyLogarithm Function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polylogarithm) and
$\ds{{\rm Li}_{1}\pars{z} = -\ln\pars{1 - z}}$.

> With the PolyLogaritm Recursive Property and $\ds{{\rm Li}_{2}\pars{0} = 0}$:
>   \begin{align}
> \color{#66f}{\large\int_{0}^{1}{t\ln\pars{t} \over 1 + t^{2}}\,\dd t}&=
> \Re\int_{0}^{\ic}{\rm Li}_{2}'\pars{t}\,\dd t=\Re{\rm Li}_{2}\pars{\ic}
> =\color{#66f}{\large -\,{\pi^{2} \over 48}}
> \end{align}

Note that
\begin{align}&\color{#c00000}{\Re{\rm Li}_{2}\pars{\ic}}
=\Re\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}{\ic^{n} \over n^{2}}
=\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}{\pars{-1}^{n} \over \pars{2n}^{2}}
={1 \over 4}\bracks{\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}{1 \over \pars{2n}^{2}}
-\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}{1 \over \pars{2n - 1}^{2}}}
\\[3mm]&={1 \over 4}\bracks{{1 \over 4}\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}{1 \over n^{2}}
-\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}{1 \over n^{2}}
+ \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}{1 \over \pars{2n}^{2}}}
=-\,{1 \over 8}\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}{1 \over n^{2}}
=-\,{1 \over 8}\,{\pi^{2} \over 6}=\color{#c00000}{-\,{\pi^{2} \over 48}}
\end{align}

> Also, $\ds{\Re{\rm Li}_{2}\pars{\ic}}$ can be calculated by means of
>   ${\sf\mbox{Jonquiere Inversion Formula}}$ as shown in the above cited link.
>
> A 'straightforward' calculation can be performed by expanding
>   $\ds{\ln\pars{1 - t}}$, in powers of $\ds{t}$, in the expression
>   $\ds{-\,\Re\int_{0}^{\ic}{\ln\pars{1 - t} \over t}\,\dd t}$.